# How to change menu link in wordpress depends on user log in status with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to change my menu last link. Like if the user is logged in then it'll appear profile link otherwise it'll appear to sign-up link.

Answer (score 2):

I am recommending you not to use javascirpt for that.

Instead use PHP. Example of code:

```
<?php if( is_user_logged_in() ):?>
    <a href="#">Profile</a>
<?php else:?>
    <a href="#">Sign up</a>
<?php endif;?>
```

If javascript fails for some reason you won't be able to output the links.

Comment: How this will change only the last menu link in WordPress? This is for some static links.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Check Body Class if User is logged in
var status = document.body.classList.contains( 'logged-in' );

if(status == 'true'){    // If Logged In then
    jQuery('.menu-main ul li:last-child a').text("profile");
    jQuery('.menu-main ul li:last-child a').attr("href", "www.google.com");
}
else{                   // If user is not Logged In Then
    jQuery('.menu-main ul li:last-child a').text("sign up");
    jQuery('.menu-main ul li:last-child a').attr("href", "www.yahoo.com");
}
```

Comment: Don't depend on css classes and javascript, use PHP like in my answer

Comment: I used classes and JS because in WordPress menu is not static and only the last link/menu needs to change. Can it be done only with PHP?